# How to set image source of BinaryImageColumnin RadGrid from byte[] array in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have the following ASP.NET:

```html
<Columns>
  <telerik:GridClientSelectColumn UniqueName="GridClientSelectColumn1" />
  <telerik:GridBinaryImageColumn UniqueName="BinaryImageColumn" />
  <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PRODUCT_NAME" SortExpression="PRODUCT_NAME" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Strings, ProductName %>" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" />
  <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="STORE_NAME" SortExpression="STORE_NAME" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Strings, Supplier %>" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" />
  <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PRODUCT_PRICE" SortExpression="PRODUCT_PRICE" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Strings, UnitPrice %>" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" />
  <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PRODUCT_QUANTITY" SortExpression="PRODUCT_QUANTITY" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Strings, Quantity %>" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" />
  <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TRANS_TOTAL" SortExpression="TRANS_TOTAL" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Strings, TotalPrice %>" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" />
</Columns>
```

Code Behind:

```js
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e) {
  SQLHelper a = new SQLHelper(SQLHelper.ConnectionStrings.KernelConnectionString);
  DataTable newdt = DataHelper.GetProductAdditionalObjects(11);
  for (int i = 0; i < newdt.Rows.Count; i++) {
    if (int.Parse(newdt.Rows[i]["PROD_OBJECT_SPECS_ID"].ToString()) == 1) {
      byte[] img = Converter.ObjectToByteArray(newdt.Rows[i]["OBJECT_BINARIES"]); //Convert Object to Byte Array
    }
  }
  GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
  if (item != null) {
    (item["BinaryImageColumn"].Controls[0] as RadBinaryImage).DataValue = img;
  }
}
```

The problem is that it gives me an error:
The name 'img' does not exist in the current context, although it is the byte array that I want to use in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image byte array could be handled in RadGrid's `ItemDataBound` event.

```
<Columns>
    <telerik:GridBinaryImageColumn UniqueName="BinaryImageColumn" />
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PRODUCT_NAME" SortExpression="PRODUCT_NAME" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Strings, ProductName %>" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" />
</Columns>

protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
   GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
   if(item != null)
   {
      (item["BinaryImageColumn"].Controls[0] as RadBinaryImage).DataValue = yourImgByteArray;
   }
}
```

> Each cell in a **GridBinaryImageColumn** contains an image streamed from a
>   binary image source field (specified through the **DataField** property of
>   the column). When used, this column will show a **RadBinaryImage** control
>   in view mode and **RadUpload** or **RadAsyncUpload** in edit mode to upload an
>   image. The type of upload is determined by the **UploadControlType**
>   property. Additionally, you can persist the binary data when an item
>   is opened for edit by setting the **PersistBinaryDataOnEdit** property to
>   **true**. This will force the control to pass the old binary image to the
>   data source so it could be persisted and not deleted.

More details can be found in the following link.

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/columns/column-types#gridbinaryimagecolumn

Comment: I followed the steps you provided however it says "The name 'img' does not exist in the current context", although I identified img as a byte[] and filled it with the required data

Comment: Where did you define your `img` variable? You might wanna check its scope and see if it does get the value in the ItemDataBound event.

Comment: I posted the proper code in my question thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my answer help to you. Fist RadGridview column add (image or txt.. etc).

```
RadGridView1.Rows.AddNew();
 RadGridView1.Rows[RadGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["Data1"].Value = byteArrayToImage(your Byte Array)
//My First Column(Data1) is ImageColumn.

public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return returnImage;
}
```